# SQl syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql_select3 = "UPDATE `pdfhash` 
SET `PdfHash` = '$pdf1hash',`DateModified` = '.$date.' 
WHERE `Filename` ='current.pdf'";
```

this SQL statement returns an error that says this

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current.pdf'',`DateModified` = 'Thursday the 30th ' WHERE `Filename` ='.current.' at line 1
```

Comment: Show us the **EXACT** query without php variables

Answer (score 4):

Incorrect quoting use like this,

```
$sql_select3 = "UPDATE `pdfhash` SET `PdfHash` = '$pdf1hash',
               `DateModified` = " . $date ." 
                WHERE `Filename` ='current.pdf'";
```

Comment: getting this error  Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current.pdf'', `DateModified` = Thursday the 30th ' at line 1

Comment: Try, `DateModified = '$date' ` not with dots

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current.pdf'', `DateModified` = 'Thursday the 30th ' ' at line 1

Comment: You need to escape 'current.pdf', because he cant read the dot. 'current\.pdf'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql_select3 = "UPDATE `pdfhash` SET `PdfHash` = '".$pdf1hash."',`DateModified` = '".$date."' WHERE `Filename` ='current.pdf'";
```

this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'.$date.'
```

With

```
'".$date."'
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql_select3 = "UPDATE `pdfhash` SET `PdfHash` = '$pdf1hash',`DateModified` = '".$date."' WHERE `Filename` ='current.pdf'";

'.$date.' to

**'".$date."'**